# Understanding the database url in JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying to use JDBC to connect with SQL but I have a problem. I got the following code from a tutorial.

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:northwind";
    String username = "";
    String password = "";
    Class.forName(driver); // load JDBC-ODBC driver
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
}
```

On the third line of the code it says `String url = "jdbc:odbc:northwind"`
I want to know what "northwind" means and how can I create one.

Comment: Perhaps you need to understand JDBC a bit more before asking questions like this?

Comment: @Moh123 i cant vote up yet, i only got one reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datbase url help you define the address of the database you are connecting to

So for connecting to a oracle database I use a url like:

```
public static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/ORCL";
```

Here is the format of the url for oracle

```
Format:- jdbc:oracle:thin:@//[HOST][:PORT]/SERVICE
```

where jdbc:oracle:thin is static part and the rest is specific to the databse you are connecting to.

Following table lists down popular JDBC driver names and database URL.

```
RDBMS   JDBC driver name                URL format
-----   ----------------                -----------------
MySQL   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver           jdbc:mysql://hostname/ databaseName
ORACLE  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port Number:databaseName
DB2     COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.net.DB2Driver  jdbc:db2:hostname:port Number/databaseName
Sybase  com.sybase.jdbc.SybDriver       jdbc:sybase:Tds:hostname: port Number/databaseName
```

All the highlighted part in URL format is static and you need to change only remaining part as per your database setup.

Source : [Tutorialpoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-db-connections.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

Download Driver from : http://afirs.googlecode.com/files/ojdbc6.jar

```
try {
  //Driver to Connect with Database
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"); 
} catch (Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
try {
  String DBlink = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@vicky-pc:1521:test"; 
  //vicky-pc: Hostname / 1521: port / test: Databasename
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DBlink, "username", "password");
  Statement smt = con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery("select * from tab");
  // rs contains all return values for your query
  while(rs.next()){
   String data = rs.getString("Column_Name");
  }
  con.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u should have googled it before coming here ...  but anyway , northwind is a nice example database that is being used for learning how to play with database.

when i was in college we used it to learn basic sql by playing on this database.

now i will explain to you what is really important here.

the driver line is used to connect the java to the right driver. i wont get into the mechanics of that  , the thing u really need to know is that each database has its own driver for java.
you need to find the driver your database is using by google.

the url line is your "setup" line. first part (XXXX:XXXX) is wich database is it. second part (wich comes right after the X thing i just explained) is usually the location of the server. again , like the driver , every database has its own setup rules.